# Sum values of each unique key in Apache Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an `RDD[(String, (Long, Long))]` where each element is not unique:

```
(com.instagram.android,(2,0))
(com.android.contacts,(6,1))
(com.android.contacts,(3,4))
(com.instagram.android,(8,3))
...
```

So I want to obtain an `RDD` where each element is the sum of the two values for every unique key:

```
(com.instagram.android,(10,3))
(com.android.contacts,(9,5))
...
```

Here is my code:

```
val appNamesAndPropertiesRdd = appNodesRdd.map({
  case Row(_, appName, totalUsageTime, usageFrequency, _, _, _, _) => 
    (appName, (totalUsageTime, usageFrequency))
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reduceByKey`:

```
val rdd = appNamesAndPropertiesRdd.reduceByKey(
  (acc, elem) => (acc._1 + elem._1, acc._2 + elem._2)
)
```

`reduceByKey` uses `aggregateByKey` described by SCouto, but has more readable usage. For your case, more advanced features of `aggregateByKey` - hidden by simpler API of `reduceBykey` - are not necessary

Comment: @Fobi Acc means Accumulator ;) Probably you mean max in the first element in Tuple. Then `appNamesAndPropertiesRdd.reduceByKey(
  (acc, elem) => Math.max(acc, elem._1)
)` Here acc will be just a Long, not Tuple, but still we reduce Tuples, that's why I call `._1` on elem

Comment: @TGaweda if I try I have an error: overloaded method value max with alternatives: (x$1: Double,x$2: Double)Double <and> (x$1: Float,x$2: Float)Float <and> (x$1: Long,x$2: Long)Long <and> (x$1: Int,x$2: Int)Int cannot be applied to ((Long, Long), Long)

Comment: @Fobi Strange. Try `appNamesAndPropertiesRdd.reduceByKey( (acc, elem) => (Math.max(acc._1, elem._1), Math.max(acc._2, elem._2)).map(x => (x._1, x._2._1)`

Comment: @TGaweda I have: value map is not a member of (Int, Int) possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value map'?

Comment: @Fobi Put extra `)` before `.map` - typo mistake ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think that usageFrequency should be simply added up.

Now, lets come to what you want to do, You want to add things by key, you can do it

1.Using `groupByKey` and then `reducing` the groups to sum things up,

```
val requiredRdd = appNamesAndPropertiesRdd
  .groupBy({ case (an, (tut, uf)) => an })
  .map({
    case (an, iter) => (
      an,
      iter
        .map({ case (an, tut, uf) => (tut, tf) })
        .reduce({ case ((tut1, tf1), (tut2, tf2)) => (tut1 + tut2, tf1 + tf2) })
    )
  })
```

Or by using `reduceByKey`

```
val requiredRdd = appNamesAndPropertiesRdd
  .reduceByKey({
    case ((tut1, uf1), (tut2, uf2)) => (tut1 + tut2, tf1 + tf2)
  })
```

And `reduceByKey` is a better choice for two reasons,

1. It saves a not so required `group` operation.
2. The `groupBy` approach can lead to a reshuffle which will be expensive.

Comment: `.groupBy({ case (an, tut, uf) => an })` is not ok, OP has `.groupBy({ case (an, (tut, uf)) => an })`

Answer (score 1):

The function `aggregateByKey` is the best one for this purpose

```
appNamesAndPropertiesRdd.aggregateByKey((0, 0))((acc, elem) => (acc._1 + elem._1, acc._2 +elem._2 ),(acc1, acc2) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2))
```

Explained here:
`aggregateByKey((0, 0))` => This is the zerovalue. The value that will be the initial one. In your case, since you want the addition, 0,0 will be the initial value (0.0, 0.0) if you want double instead of int

`((acc, elem) => (acc._1 + elem._1, acc._2 +elem._2 )` => The first function. To accumulate the elements in the same partition. The accumulator will hold the partial value. Since elem is a tuple, you need to add each part of it to the correpondent part of the accumulator

`(acc1, acc2) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2))` => The second function. To accumulate the accumulator from each partition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic,

```
rdd.groupBy(_._1).map(x=> (x._1, (x._2.map(_._2).foldLeft((0,0)) {case ((acc1, acc2),(a, b))=> (acc1+a, acc2+b)} )))
```

Comment: It would be slower than reduceByKey